# How to get a participant list of multiple events ordered by event name

Tags: civievent, civireport

I want to get a list of participants of multiple events ordered by event name (primary) and participant name (secondary) but I don't know how to accomplish this with CiviReport. The result should look like this:

[image]

I'm only able to sort by the participants name. And group by event name results a list of events, not participants.

Currently I'm using CiviCRM version 4.6.10. In 4.3.4 it was possible to accomplish such a list but I'm not able to reuse those reports (blank screen on request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which report template are you using?

I'm able to bring up a list like this using the Event Participant Report (list), just by sorting by Event and then name - by default it sorts by name first - and not using any grouping.

It doesn't change the column layout - it still has the name first, but it is ordered by event first.

(I have noticed some old saved reports failing after upgrades, but haven't had problems recreating them)

Comment: I've used Participant list Count Report because I'm not able to create a new report based on the Event Participant Report (List) template. I always get a blank screen because civicrm is trying to open a file in the directory /CRM/Report/Form/Event/ParticipantListing which doesn't exists. This file seems to be missing since my previous crm update (deleted the whole civicrm directory). I guess it was a custom template.

Comment: I solved my template problem by searching the database for the class name "CRM_Report_Form_Event_ParticipantListing_NameOfTheMissingFile" and trimed it to "CRM_Report_Form_Event_ParticipantListing" (table civicrm_option_value). Now I'm able to access Event Participant Report (list) and can create a participant list of multiple events ordered by event name. Weird update hassle.